# Create container.html.twig template for specific page

Tags: theming, 8

I'm attempting to edit the search page.
I've edited container.html.twig to contain

```
{%
  set classes = [
    has_parent ? 'js-form-wrapper',
    has_parent ? 'form-wrapper',
  ]
%}
<h2>Search Results</h2>
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ children }}</div>
```

It works fine when I leave the file name as container.html.twig. But I'd like for it to only apply to the search page. I've tried naming it container--search-results.html.twig but that did not work.

How do I rename container.twig.html to only apply to my search page?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this contains the answer, but you should definitely read this:

[Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392)

Comment: It does not. Twig debugging is what I used to figure out that container.twig.html was being used at that point, but it did not show me how I could write a custom one specifically for that page.

Comment: ah okey! Wanted to make sure you know it! Further investigation is needed!